# JsonSerializer Struct with asp-net core 3.0

Tags: json, serialization, struct, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm having issues with .net core 3.0 when I convert a struct to a json. (with wasn't a problem when I was using .net core 2.2)

This is my struct

```
[Serializable]
struct Item
{
   public int A;
   public string B;
   public int C;
   public decimal D;
   public decimal E;
}
```

This is my code

```
var linhas = COD_PRODUTO.Count;
Item[] item = new Item[linhas];

for (int cont = 0; cont < linhas; cont++)
{
   DESCRICAO = _context.Produtos.Where(c => c.COD_PRODUTO == COD_PRODUTO[cont]).Select(c => 
   c.DESCRICAO).Single().ToString();

   item[cont].A = COD_PRODUTO[cont];
   item[cont].B = DESCRICAO;
   item[cont].C = QUANTIDADE[cont];
   item[cont].D = PRECOUNITARIO[cont];
   item[cont].E = TOTAL[cont];
}

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item); //3.0
Debug.WriteLine("----------------------" + json);

return new JsonResult(json);
```

It's returning me empty values, any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 3.0, ASP.NET Core uses the `System.Text.Json` to serialize/deserialize json. And  the public properties are serialized by default.  See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialization-behavior):

> **Serialization behavior**
>
> By default, all public properties are serialized.

1. To fix that issue, you could **change** those public **fields** to public **properties** as below:

   ```
   [Serializable]
   struct Item
   {
       public int A {get;set;}
       public string B {get;set;}
       public int C {get;set;}
       public decimal D {get;set;}
       public decimal E {get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. Or as an alternative, you can follow [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support) to fallback to the old behavior by using the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) package:

   ```cs
   services.AddControllers()
       .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>{ /*...*/ });
   ```